# How can I debug this unexplained Openshift 3 pod going into crashloop when serving a spring boot app?

Tags: kubernetes, maven-plugin, spring-boot-test, openshift-3

I am trying to move a Spring boot application onto a openshift 3 cluster.  I am using the Maven fabric8 plugin to generate most of the openshift boilerplate config as well as performing the S2I build.  When my pod starts up I can see in the log output that the application starts up but right after spring boot defaults to the default profile (I didn't set a profile yet) the app crashes and the only output I see in the Openshift log is Killed...  I couldn't find anything of value googleing except it seemed that it could be openJDK that tries to grab more memory than is a available for a single pod.  I added a fabric8 fragment that limits the memory a single container is able to use but I still get the same error when I start up the pod.  I ran OC describe pod and saw a exit code 143.  i'm running out of ideas and would appreciate  Any idea on how I can debug this further/how to resolve this sort of issue?  Also not sure if this is related but even though my application.yml is set up to enable SSL the route that fabric8 creates is always a HTTP URL and not a HTTPS URL.  i'm wondering if that could be the cause of the pod going into a crashloop as the readinessProbe and wellnessProbe can't hit the actuator endpoints?

The console output, maven pom file, application.yml and fabric8 config is below.

```
console output:


  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.3.RELEASE)

2020-06-27 10:14:06.297  INFO 8 --- [           main] com.xib.vodacom.ans.AnsApplicationKt     : Starting AnsApplicationKt v1.0.9 on vc-ans-1-bzlxc-debug with PID 8 (/deployments/vc-ans-1.0.9.jar started by ? in /deployments)
2020-06-27 10:14:06.396 DEBUG 8 --- [           main] com.xib.vodacom.ans.AnsApplicationKt     : Running with Spring Boot v2.1.3.RELEASE, Spring v5.1.4.RELEASE
2020-06-27 10:14:06.397  INFO 8 --- [           main] com.xib.vodacom.ans.AnsApplicationKt     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
Killed
sh-4.2$                                                                                                                                     


oc describe pod output:

   Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  certs
    Optional:    false
  default-token-8pts4:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-8pts4
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       Burstable
Node-Selectors:  node-role.kubernetes.io/compute=true
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/memory-pressure:NoSchedule
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age              From                                 Message
  ----     ------     ----             ----                                 -------
  Normal   Scheduled  6m               default-scheduler                    Successfully assigned cx-ans-prod/vc-ans-1-bzlxc to pocpap8zadsas.cc.corp
  Normal   Created    5m (x3 over 6m)  kubelet, asdf.cc.corp  Created container
  Normal   Started    5m (x3 over 6m)  kubelet, asdfgf.cc.corp  Started container
  Normal   Killing    5m (x2 over 6m)  kubelet, asdfgf.cc.corp  Killing container with id docker://spring-boot:Container failed liveness probe.. Container will be killed and recreated.
  Warning  Unhealthy  5m (x7 over 6m)  kubelet, asdfgf.cc.corp  Readiness probe failed: Get https://192.168.31.110:8080/actuator/health: dial tcp 192.168.31.110:8080: connect: connection refused
  Warning  Unhealthy  5m (x7 over 6m)  kubelet, asdfgf.cc.corp  Liveness probe failed: Get https://192.168.31.110:8080/actuator/health: dial tcp 192.168.31.110:8080: connect: connection refused
  Normal   Pulled     1m (x7 over 6m)  kubelet, asdfgf.cc.corp  Container image "docker-registry.default.svc:5000/cx-ans-prod/vc-ans@sha256:4f39366bddc1e4ce7ed3c7e320453fbe6e90c4100f860a82ec87b04e7fb7e5b1" already present on machine

C:\dev\xib-ans-bo>


                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                            
pom.xml:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.xib</groupId>
  <artifactId>vc-ans</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.9</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>     
    <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>

  <scm>
    <connection>scm:git:git://pgitap1zatcrh.vodacom.corp:XIB/xib-ans-bo.git</connection>    
    <url>git://pgitap1zatcrh.vodacom.corp:XIB/xib-ans-bo.git</url>
</scm>

  <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <kotlin.version>1.3.61</kotlin.version>
    <fabric8.mode>openshift</fabric8.mode>    
    <fabric8.namespace>cx-ans-prod</fabric8.namespace>
    </properties>


  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
      <version>2.3</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>tomcat-annotations-api</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
          <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>tomcat-annotations-api</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
          <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>tomcat-annotations-api</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
          <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>tomcat-annotations-api</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
          <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>tomcat-annotations-api</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
          <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>tomcat-annotations-api</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
          <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-data</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>tomcat-annotations-api</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
          <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>tomcat-annotations-api</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
          <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
      <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>tomcat-annotations-api</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
          <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>tomcat-annotations-api</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
          <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-module-kotlin</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>tomcat-annotations-api</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
          <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
      <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
      <version>25.1-jre</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>tomcat-annotations-api</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
          <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
      <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>tomcat-annotations-api</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
          <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
      <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.21</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>tomcat-annotations-api</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
          <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
      <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.21</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>tomcat-annotations-api</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
          <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
      <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
      <version>4.5.6</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>tomcat-annotations-api</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
          <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
      <groupId>com.oracle.ojdbc</groupId>
      <version>19.3.0.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>tomcat-annotations-api</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
          <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlinx</groupId>
      <artifactId>kotlinx-coroutines-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>tomcat-annotations-api</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
          <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
          <groupId>*</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-restdocs-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-restdocs-mockmvc</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.21</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.21</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jre7</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.21</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jre8</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.21</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk7</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.21</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.21</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.21</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>import</scope>
        <type>pom</type>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <type>pom</type>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>  
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</testSourceDirectory>
    <plugins>

    <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <args>
                        <arg>-Xjsr305=strict</arg>
                    </args>
                    <compilerPlugins>
                        <plugin>spring</plugin>
                    </compilerPlugins>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
        <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
                        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>
    
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>        
        <configuration>
          <executable>true</executable>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
        <artifactId>fabric8-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.1</version>
        <configuration>          
          <generateRoute>true</generateRoute>
            <enricher>
              <config>
              <fmp-service>
                <name>ans-service</name>
                <type>ClusterIP</type>
              </fmp-service>
              </config>
            </enricher>              
            <enricher>
              <config>
                <fmp-maven-scm-enricher>>
                  <scm-tag>https</scm-tag>
                </fmp-maven-scm-enricher>>
              </config>
            </enricher>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>resource</goal>
              <goal>build</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    </build>  
</project>




fabric8 deployment.yml fragment:

spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - env:
          - name: SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE
          value: qa
          volumeMounts:
            - name: certs
              mountPath: /opt/certs
              readOnly: true
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /actuator/health
              port: 8080
              scheme: HTTPS
              initialDelaySeconds: 30
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /actuator/health
              port: 8080
              scheme: HTTPS
              initialDelaySeconds: 30
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: "64Mi"
            limits:
              memory: "256Mi"
          env:
            - name: JVM_OPTS
              value: "-Xms64M -Xmx256M"
      volumes:
        - name: certs
          secret:
            secretName: certs
            items:
              - key: ans.pfx
                path: ans.pfx
              - key: vb_pp_client_ans.jks
                path: vb_pp_client_ans.jks
              - key: vc_truststore.jks
                path: vc_truststore.jks




spring boot application.yml:

app:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
    url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@qgeno.cc.corp
    username: asdfgf
    password: asdfgf
    connection-test-query: SELECT 1 from dual
    pool-name: ANS_CP
    minimum-idle: 3
    maximum-pool-size: 20

alive:
  file: /opt/apps/xib/vc-ans/running.txt

spring:
  main:
    allow-bean-definition-overriding: true

vb:
  vb-url: "https://asdfgf.cc.corp"
  hc-check-msisdn: "0821341111"
  ssl-cert-password: "asdfgf"
  ssl-cert-alias: "asdfgf"
  keystore-path: "/opt/certs/vb_pp_client_ans.jks"
  
  repeat-caller-url: https://asdfgf.cc.corp

server:
  http:
    port: 8080
  ssl:
    enabled: true
    protocol: TLS
    key-alias: lkjhj
    key-store: /opt/certs/ans.pfx
    key-store-password: asdfgf
    trust-store: /opt/certs/vc_truststore.jks
    trust-store-password: asdfgf

logging:
  level:
    com.xib: DEBUG

management:
  server:
    ssl:
      key-store: /opt/certs/ans.pfx
      key-store-password: asdfgf
  endpoint:
    health:
      show-details: always
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error code 143 is `SIGTERM` which Kubernetes uses to shutdown pods. This means Kubernetes wants your pod killed for a reason. There are 3 options that I think might be the case:

1: As you said, it can be triggered by memory allocation greater than given memory limit. In that case Kubernetes will just kill your pod and keeps node stable but if it was cpu limit then Kubernetes could limit the resource allocation and wouldn't kill the pod. You can check if resource limit is lower than your app requirement by running this command: `oc get deployment deployment_name -o yaml`

2: AS @Arghya Sadhu said, you could have misconfigured actuator somehow, try to check if liveness and readiness probe are correctly set and gives correct output. You can also get this configuration by above command.

3: Everything works great except your app takes too much to get ready and Kubernetes decides your app is misbehaving. This could be problem if you set resource limitations too narrow and your java app has too little resource to get prepared in time.

Comment: So turned out it was the readiness/liveness probes causing the pods to be recreated.  when I run my application locally and hit /actuator/health I get a status of up but on OPenshift it's always down...  Any ideas?

Comment: you create openshift deployment created automatically and it may be `/health` default value, you can check it with get deploy command and check "liveness check" path. Then either update that in deployment or change your app's healt check paths.

Answer (score 1):

Add below in the `application.yml`

```
management.endpoint.health.group.readiness.include=*
management.endpoint.health.group.readiness.show-details=always

management.endpoint.health.group.liveness.include=ping
management.endpoint.health.group.liveness.show-details=never
```

Use `/actuator/health/readiness` for readiness and `/actuator/health/liveness` for liveness in the deployment.yaml

```
readinessProbe:
  httpGet:
    port: healthcheck
    path: /actuator/health/readiness
  initialDelaySeconds: 10
livenessProbe:
  httpGet:
    port: healthcheck
    path: /actuator/health/liveness
  initialDelaySeconds: 60
  periodSeconds: 1
```

Additionally, if Spring Security is present, you would need to add custom security configuration that allows unauthenticated access to the endpoints as shown in the following example:

```
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
public class ActuatorSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.requestMatcher(EndpointRequest.toAnyEndpoint()).authorizeRequests((requests) ->
            requests.anyRequest().permitAll());
    }

}
```

If you deploy applications behind a firewall, you may prefer that all your actuator endpoints can be accessed without requiring authentication. You can do so by changing the `management.endpoints.web.exposure.include` property, as follows in

`application.yaml`

`management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*`

Comment: i'm trying to test this locally but don't get anything back after adding that config and navigating to /actuator/health/readiness or liveness.  wondering if this could be spring security blocking me?

Comment: If this was spring security issue then you would have got a 401...can you share output of http://localhost:8080/actuator/health Also add management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=health in the application yaml

Comment: readiness probe scheme: HTTPS ...try changing it to HTTP

Comment: liveness and readiness probe were introduced in spring boot 2.3. Here he's using spring boot 2.1